# How to know when a message has been dismissed with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am adding announcements into my app which is basically a personal message to users. They recieve the message then if they dismissed it I want to stop showing that specific again.

this is my php

```
  <?     $the_ID = $res_announcement->formal_announcement_id;  ?>

 <form action method="POST">


<div class="fade in pi-alert-warning pi-no-margin-bottom hide_msg_announcement">
      <div class="pi-section pi-row-sm hide_msg_announcement">
        <p class="pi-weight-600 pi-no-margin-bottom hide_msg_announcement">
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle pi-text-orange yellow blink_me" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="pi-text-dark"><?= $content_body ?></span>
            <?= $url_setup_pm ?>.
        </p>
  <div class=" pull-right checkbox checkbox-inline" style="margin-top: -16px;">
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide_msg_announcement" name="hide_msg" id="hide_msg_announcement" value="yes">
  <label class="pi-smaller-text pi-text-grey" for="hide_msg_announcement">dismiss</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

then I am hiding it with Jquery but i dont know how to store this specific messages ID or how get it from anywhere. I tried passing php variables but always gets null. I need a way to store the messages ID so I know not to display that message again to the user

```
 jQuery('body').on('change', '.hide_msg_announcement', function(e) {
    jQuery(".hide_msg_announcement").hide();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {            
        $.ajax({
            url: 'on_off.php',
            dataType:'json',
            async:true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { strID:$(this)},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Two side notes.  `$(this).is(':checked')` and `$(this).attr('id')` are anti-patterns.  They are an over reliance on jQuery to do logic that is already available on native elements, you already have a reference to.  `this.checked` and `this.id` will give you the same values, without having to instantiate a new jQuery object just to gain access to its methods.

Comment: `strID: $(this)` won't work. `$(this)` is a JQuery object, not a string you can send to the server.

Comment: What is the value you want to send to the server from the example HTML?

Comment: Taplar's suggestion was that you change `strID: $(this).attr("id")` to `strID: this.id`

Comment: But it's not clear that the ID is what you want to send. The ID of the checkbox is just `hide_msg_announcement`, it doesn't identify the specific message.

Comment: @barmar thats what im trying to find out, what is best data to send to know the messaged was dismissed. I have an id of the message from the database but i dont know how to send it

Comment: ill try it again and update you in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `$the_ID` in the HTML so that jQuery can access it. You can use a `data-` attribute for this.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hide_msg_announcement" name="hide_msg" id="hide_msg_announcement" data-msg="<?php echo $the_ID; ?>" value="yes">
```

Then jQUery can use:

```
data: {strID: $(this).data("msg");},
```